# How do I receive JSON formated data into C# method argument

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, webkit

I am using WebKit browser control in my .net application. I am also new to JSON and have little knowledge of Java script. My is to call one method C# method from java script  code. I know there is "ObjectForScripting" property with WebKit control.

**C# Code:- This code get executed on one of the button click. Which inject java script into rendered HTML page.**

```
Element scriptElm = browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
scriptElm.AppendChild(browser.Document.CreateTextNode("Test(['ABC','EFG'],{'name':'First Name','surname':'LastName'})"));

NodeList headElm = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head");
headElm[0].AppendChild(scriptElm);
```

Above code calls below Java script method from rendered HTML page.

**Java Script code:**

```
function Test(arg1,arg2)
{ 
    document.write(arg2.name); // Printing correct i.e. Firstname
    document.write(arg2); // Bad!!!! always print [Object object]   
    window.external.TestMethod(arg1,arg2); // Call method in C# code.
}
```

**C# Method signature**

```
public bool TestMethod(string obj1, String obj2)
{
            MessageBox.Show(obj1.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(obj2.ToString());
            return true;
}
```

So in above callback method I am not able to get second parameter i.e.obj2 correctly. In C#. I always get it as Object. I tried setting that to Object but didn't work.How should I convert it into right format?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying changing your method signature to:

```
public bool TestMethod(object obj1, object obj2)
```

Set a breakpoint on it and have a look at the types you are actually receiving. Also, if the breakpoint doesn't hit, you have a different problem.

Comment: Yes I found it!!!!! :). I need to use JSON.Stringify(arg2) and then pass it from the script to C#. Well!!! then again I need to convert back to object using some JSON library for .NET.:) :)

Comment: JSON.NET or JavascriptSerializer